# MSMQ synchronous writing to remote queue

Tags: c#, msmq

I need confirmed delivery to a remote queue and according to MSDN [`Exists()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.messaging.messagequeue.exists(v=vs.110).aspx) method does not support remote queue check.

According to me message delivery can fail in the following two scenarios

- Remote machine is not reachable.
- Queue on the machine does not exist or was deleted.

I am using transactional queue. Setting `AdministrationQueue` and `UseDeadLetterQueue` ensures messages are not lost.

But I want a synchronous way to send message to remote machine queue. Does MSMQ supports this and how is it possible even if it's not supported by design?

Answer (score 0):

> Does MSMQ supports this and how is it possible even if it's not
>   supported by design?

The MSMQ service does not have any built-in way to support duplex messaging.

In order to achieve this, you will need to code on both ends of the queued channel. However, this is generally complex at best.

The following link describes how to achieve this by using System.Messaging:

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/999238/Efficient-Message-Correlation-in-MSMQ

It is based on using the CorrelationId header with the ReceiveByCorrelationId() operation, which is notoriously bad for performance reasons.

Another way of doing this is by using WCF, however, this still relies on a manual response using System.Messaging:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms751435(v=vs.110).aspx

A further approach uses WCF and a helper library called [Duplex MSMQ](https://duplexmsmq.codeplex.com/):

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/41907/WCF-Duplex-MSMQ

However, none of these methods is very nice and all introduce unwanted complexity.

> I need confirmed delivery to a remote queue

I guess what we need to understand is what you mean by "confirmed". If you use a transactional queue, then this provides a guaranteed delivery semantic on a message transmission from one application to another.

If, on the other hand, you require a real-time response, then using message queuing is probably not the right technology for your purposes.

If you're forced to use MSMQ, then you could do worse than using a commercial product. I have used [NServiceBus](https://particular.net/nservicebus) extensively, which uses MSMQ but adds powerful message exchange patterns such as request-reply. It is a pay-for product, but if you only require a single threaded operation, then you could use the free version.

> What I needed was real-time response for success and fail messages..

If I understand this correctly, then your requirement is acknowledgement, which MSMQ does support. See:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms978430.aspx#bdadotnetasync2_topic4

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms707129(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: That's a great response.
Yes, you are correct. I am using tranactional queues for "Comfirmed Delivery". What I needed was real-time response for success and fail messages also, so that I can stop sending more messages to the queue.

The first codeproject article that you mentioned is not suitable in my scenario. The consumer of the message is a windows service that reads from the target queue. If we wait for the message with CorrelationID on that queue we can enter race condition where the message is picked up first and we will still wait for the message.

Comment: @Xlr8 - why do you need queued transport? Also, are you talking about request-reply, or do you just need acknowledgement?

Comment: I need request-reply. I should wait till the message is either recieved or rejected.
I know MSMQ is meant for disconnected systems, but in my case let's assume the systems are online.